# Get the value of an element child in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value of an element child. Here is the element :

```
<li id="1" style="display:normal">
    <h2 id="label_lg">Temp Set (º<span class="degsign">C</span>)</h2>
    <p id="ihi" style="color:teal;font-size:3vw;">--</p>
</li>
```

I would like to get the value of `<p></p>`, if possible in javascript. I've tried to use

```
document.getElementById(1).childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

and

```
var o = document.getElementById(i).children
o[1].nodeValue
```

Nothing worked, the alert always returns `null`.

Comment: A paragraph doesn't have a value, it has `innerHTML` or `innerText` or even `textContent`

Comment: `document.querySelector('#1 p').innerHTML`

Comment: I suggest you do not use numeric IDs. Although valid in some versions of HTML, I do not recommend using them at all.

Comment: What is `style="display:normal"` supposed to be? `normal` is not a valid CSS property for `display`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've specified jQuery:

```
$('#1 p').text();
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

#### innerText || textContent

These will give you text of element. If you have nested elements like a `small` tag inside `p`, you will get text of all.

#### innerHTML

This will return HTML of the element. If you have nested elements, it will not return text, but a raw html of that element. But if element does not have a child, then output will be same.

```js
(function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById('1');
  var _innerText = parent.innerText;
  var _innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
  var _textContent = parent.textContent;

  console.log(_innerText, _innerHTML, _textContent)
})()
```

```html
<li id="1" style="display:normal">
  <h2 id="label_lg">Temp Set (º<span class="degsign">C</span>)</h2>
  <p id="ihi" style="color:teal;font-size:3vw;">--</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var pString = document.getElementById("ihi").value;
```

and to change the value:

```
pString.innerHTML = "Your string"
```

Comment: This is all kinds of wrong. `document.getElementById("ihi").value` is undefined because `ihi`, a `p` element, doesn't have a value property. `document.getElementById("ihi").innerText` would do the job, but it would return a string. You can set an `innerHTML` property on a string, but it's not going to have any effect on the UI. `document.getElementById("ihi").innerText = "Your string"` would work for that.

Answer (score 0):

with JS

```js
alert(document.getElementById('ihi').innerHTML)
```

```html
<li id="1" style="display:normal">
      <h2 id="label_lg">Temp Set (º<span class="degsign">C</span>)</h2>
      <p id="ihi" style="color:teal;font-size:3vw;">--</p>
 </li>
```

with JQUERY:

```js
alert($('#ihi').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="1" style="display:normal">
      <h2 id="label_lg">Temp Set (º<span class="degsign">C</span>)</h2>
      <p id="ihi" style="color:teal;font-size:3vw;">--</p>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the innerText property:

```
alert(document.getElementById(1).childNodes[1].innerText);
// Alerts "--"
```

**In case you want to use jQuery**:

```
alert($("1").child("#ihi").html())
```